# KendoUI Autocomplete list appears on top of the textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am making my first steps with KendoUI for MVC. I have a very simple model that reads a table "Products" from the database and passes it to the view as a strongly type model.

I am using the Model to bind it to the autocomplete to get the suggested values. This works almost fine. This is done using the following Razor syntax:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
     .Name("productAutoComplete")
     .DataTextField("Name")
     .BindTo(Model)
     .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
     .Placeholder("Select the product")
     .Suggest(true)
)
```

The problem that I have is that the dropdown list that has the suggestions for the autocomplete appears on top of the textbox itself (instead of right below it).

Please see the image below without typing anything in the autocomplete field:

[image: without typing anything in the field]

And with the autocomplete in action:
[image: after starting to type something]

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Lefteris

Comment: Have you included the proper CSS files on your page? Kendo won't render properly without those.

Comment: I setup the project using the "Telerik Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC VSExtensions". I suppose that it has included the right CSS (as far as I can see)

Comment: I suspect some floating divs are messing it up, but hard to say. The CSS thing is kinda common, but it looks like you have the files linked already. Open up your Chrome element inspector and see if you can figure out if one of the enclosing elements is breaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have overcome the problem by using the latest jQuery library (1.9.1) instead of the one shipped with KendoUI (1.7.1).

I am still not sure why this was not working with 1.7.1 (it is ok with 1.9.0+).

In any case KendoUI latest version (Q1 2013) ships with 1.9.1 jQuery. Unfortunatelly this doesn't seem to be available yes as a trial for KendoUI Complete for ASP.NET MVC

I hope this solution helps someone else.

Lefteris